# std::basic_string<T>::size_type causes compile error in C++20 mode

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, dependent-name

Here is a simple code that MSVC 2022 compiles in C++17 mode, but fails in C++20 mode:

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    std::basic_string<T>::size_type bar_size; //This fails to compile in C++20
}
```

The error being reported in C++20 mode does not help explain the reason: `error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier' following 'expression'`

Interestingly, it only happens inside templated functions, this counterexample compiles fine in C++20 mode (as well as in C++17):

```
void baz()
{
    std::basic_string<char>::size_type bar_size;
}
```

The only way I can fix the problem so far is to use auto instead of explicit data type, for example like so:

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    std::basic_string<T> bar;
    auto bar_size = bar.size();
}
```

But I really want to learn what has changed in C++20 compared to C++17 that causes this syntax to be invalid instead of just mindlessly applying a workaround patch.

Comment: Nothing changed for such declarations. It's just MSVC's journey to compliance... is spotty.

Comment: `std::basic_string<T>::size_type bar_size;` is never valid in standard C++. In C++20 mode, MSVC enables [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160) by default, which correctly flags this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
typename std::basic_string<T>::size_type bar_size;
```

The name `size_type` is a dependent name.

Comment: can you explain why this works, what this has to do with the indicated duplicate and what changed between 17 and 20 - please

Comment: @pm100 Nothing was changed. With absence of the keyword typename the compiler considers the record as an expression. Maybe the compiler was made more compliant with the C Standard

Comment: @pm100 Indeed, it seems like MSVC in C++17 mode was failing to comply with the standard by allowing me to get away without using the typename keyword in this case. And when MS introduced C++20 support, they have fixed that in C++20 mode, but have not fixed it in C++17 mode. Perhaps I should file a bug report with MS...

Comment: It probably is on purpose not to break existing code relying on it.